# How to change an object in an array by user input?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I have a number of arrays, and I would like to let the user change some of the data if he wants to by user input. I think i should use a scanner, but I'm not exactly clear of how to do this.

The arrays are stored in a class called database

```
private Student[] arrayStudents;
public DepotDatabase() {
    arrayStudents = new Driver[4];
    arrayStudents[0] = new Student("First", "Second", 1234, 1234); // sample student
    arrayStudents[1] = new Student("First 1", "Second2" , 4444, 4444); // sample student
```

This is what the data in the arrays are called in a another class called Student.

```
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int username, int password) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

and in another class called *SetUpCourse* I would like to let the user to change the name of a student by user input, and also change the username from e.g **arrayStudent[0]** to **arrayStudent[1]** like the **password**

I think I would have something like this in *SetUpWorkSchedule*

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a password");
setPassword() = scan.nextLine();
database.printArrayStudent();
```

Now to print out the array i have a method called *printArrayStudent* and this prints out all the students.

Comment: This is not a question. Please come back with a specific question after you have tried something.

Comment: It's simple, add *setter* and *getter* methods to `Student` class. `arrayStudents[0].setUsername("....")` ......etc.

Comment: I changed the question, and i also made my question more clear. I hope this helps you review the question again, and hopefully be helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Student` class should be like this:

```
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    //and do for other global variables lastName,userNAme,Password..
    //parametric constructor
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int username, int password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
    //and default constructor
}
```

Then you can change any information about student as mentioned in comments like this:

```
arrayStudents[0].setUserName("username");
arrayStudents[0].setFirstName("firstname");
arrayStudents[0].setLastName("lastname");
//......
```